# Share Viewmodel between BottomSheetDialogFragment with normal Fragment not working (observe function not trigger)

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, bottom-sheet, android-viewmodel

I want to share the same Viewmodel between my base fragment along with opened BottomSheetDialogFragment

So this is how i observe to same viewmodel between these two fragment.

BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public class TasteFilterBottomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private FilterTasteListViewModel filterTasteListViewModel;

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        filterTasteListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(),
                viewModelFactory).get(FilterTasteListViewModel.class);

        filterTasteListViewModel.init();
        observeViewModel(filterTasteListViewModel);
    }

    private void observeViewModel(FilterTasteListViewModel filterTasteListViewModel) {
        filterTasteListViewModel.getFilterTastes().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<String> tasteList) {
                // Only this one trigger when viewModel is updated
                Log.d("Bottom Dialog", tasteList.toString());
                filterTasteList = tasteList;
                setFilterButtonState(filterTasteList);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My base Fragment

```
public class FoodListFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private static TasteFilterBottomDialogFragment tasteFilterBottomDialogFragment;

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        showFoodListFilterButton();

        if (mFoodList != null) {
            mFoodListAdapter.setFoodList(mFoodList);
        }

        final FilterTasteListViewModel filterTasteListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(),
                viewModelFactory).get(FilterTasteListViewModel.class);

        filterTasteListViewModel.init();
        observeFilterTasteListViewModel(filterTasteListViewModel);
    }

    private void observeFilterTasteListViewModel(FilterTasteListViewModel filterTasteListViewModel) {
        filterTasteListViewModel.getFilterTastes().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<String> filterTasteList) {
                // This only trigger on the first time that fragment is initialise
                Log.d("FoodList", filterTasteList.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My ViewModel

```
public class FilterTasteListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<ArrayList<String>> filterTastesObservable;

    public LiveData<ArrayList<String>> getFilterTastes() {
        return this.filterTastesObservable;
    }

    public void setFilterTastes(ArrayList<String> filterTastes) {
        ((MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>) this.filterTastesObservable).postValue(filterTastes);
    }

}
```

So when i called `setFilterTastes` only this line is being called

```
Log.d("Bottom Dialog", tasteList.toString());
```

But actually this line should being called as well (but it is not).

```
Log.d("FoodList", filterTasteList.toString());
```

My question is how can i make the observable inside my baseFragment working same as inside my BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to change the observe, instead of 'this' try with 'getActivity()' with that should work.

Comment: were you able to find the solutions?

Comment: Any solution on this?